# Help needed to make my site as Aggregator

Tags: rss, feed

I am having a doubt about using "Cron Job" .

I have installed a Plugin named FeedWordpress which lets us to publish RSS feeds .It has given me an option to publish automatically or to publish by setting cron Jobs .

Could any one guide me to set these Cron Job? I have no Idea on it .This is the message it given for that configuration .

> If you want to use a cron job, you can
>   perform scheduled updates by sending
>   regularly-scheduled requests to
>   http://......?update_feedwordpress=1
>   For example, inserting the following
>   line in your crontab:
>
> */10 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://......?update_feedwordpress=1
>   will check in every 10 minutes and
>   check for updates on any feeds that
>   are ready to be polled for updates.

I have another doubt .Is there any possibility to slow down and affects the load (It is of shared hosting ) ,if I turn on the Automatic Updates of feeds?How does it helps me If I use cron Job and put a cetain limit? So that it affects the server load only when It updates the feeds .

Is there any chance to suspend my hosting account by Host If I  Make my Blog as Aggregator  because of high loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron is job scheduling mechanism in Unix-based operating systems. It depends on your hosting if you have access to it.

Since WordPress needs to run some tasks periodically it has own PHP-based mechanism called WP-Cron that is both used by core and accessible to plugins.

Basically OS cron is more reliable, WP-Cron is more compatible.

`Automatic updates` most likely refers to plugin using WP-Cron.

How much this might be issue with hosting depends on:

- hosting policy for background processes
- hosting CPU quotas (and bandwidth quotas if they are low enough and you poll often enough)
- amount and rate of updates you perform

Comment: 'hosting policy for background processes' -Hostgator has 25 concurrent processes limit where as my other host don't have such concurrent process limit .The hosting is of unlimited plan .

Comment: I assume WP Cron counts as single process, it should not spawn multiple instance. Although I had encountered that it can do that in some cases (most likely configuration issues of specific server). If in doubt it's always better to check with hosting support about such issues, rather than third parties.